# Memory efficient matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

What is the most memory efficient algorithm for calculating $A\cdot B$, where $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?
The result of this multiplication might be stored in one of the given matrices ($A$ or $B$). The 'ideal' algorithm would perform calculations with $O(1)$ additional memory and return $A\cdot B$ and $B$

Comment: Any specific motivation for this question? Or some background that might be helpful?

Comment: @Survit: Recently I've been working on some econometric models where data might change. It is highly inefficient to calculate erverything from the scrath, so I was thinking about some better way and I found it for some special case of 'very' sparse matrix. That made me think about more generale case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Brice.Boyer/pdf/winoschedule.pdf) may help.

Comment: @alpoge: I haven't read this article, just a quick look on the conclusions but it seems that it might be helpful. I found such a sentence "If the input matrices can be overwritten, we proposed a fully in-place schedule for the operation C ← A × B with - out any extra operations." Without reading whole article I can't tell whether they meant extra space apart from A and B or apart from A,B and C. Strassen-Winograd’s algorithm might (this is just an oppinion, I need to read more about this algorithm) need even more memory than the naive algorithm.

Comment: Well, from their abstract:
"In particular, we show two fully in-place schedules:
one having the same number of operations, if the input ma-
trices can be overwritten; the other one, slightly increasing
the constant of the leading term of the complexity, if the
input matrices are read-only"

Comment: Sadly, link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if $O(1)$ is possible, but $O(n)$ obviously is. Since $n=o(n^2),$ this is good enough for any practical purpose, *if* you are multiplying dense matrices. If your matrices are *not* dense, you can do better, but how much better, and how, obviously depends on the problem, so we are back to @Suvrit's question.